# How to Format a Date Column in Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, format

I have a dataframe `df` that look like this:

```
   ID Date
0  1  2008-01-24 
1  2  2007-02-17
```

The format of `Date` is `%Y-%m-%d`

How can I format the dates to `%m-%d-%Y` format?

I tried using this syntax but it did not give the right format:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`.dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer from root only works if the `Date` column contains `datetime` instances. The dataframe shown by the original poster indicates that the `Date` column contains `date` instances. This leads to an `AttributeError` with the message `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.

So you have to convert the `date`s to `datetime`s before you can format them, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(x, datetime.min.time()))
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
```