# Series format pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image: XLS FILE]

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import os

# get username
user = os.getlogin()


def file_process():
    data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\My Documents\\XINVST.xls')

    # Change the date and time formatting
    data["INVDAT"] = data["INVDAT"].apply(lambda x: datetime.combine(x, datetime.min.time()))
    data["INVDAT"] = data["INVDAT"].dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

    print(data)

    # output to new file
    # new_data = data
    # new_data.to_excel('C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\Desktop\\XINVST.xls', index=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_process()
```

I'm trying to format the INVDAT column to correct date format like 11/25/19, I've tried multiple solutions but keep running into errors like this one: TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not int, I then tried to convert the integer to date type but it errors also.

Comment: This is no place to do your homework for you.
Show what you've tried so far and why it may have failed.

Comment: In other news: look over there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709558/how-to-format-a-date-column-in-pandas

Comment: Very funny, I'm 65 years old and well beyond my school years. Thanks

Comment: Tried the solution from the link provided, got an error df["INVDAT"] = df["INVDAT"].dt.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")                                                
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Please have a look at this answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59174566/3458484

Comment: error: TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not int

Comment: Tried adding ``` data["INVDAT"] = pd.to_datetime(data["INVDAT"]) ``` but it formats the data incorrectly

Comment: I think you need to cast the field to string and the apply the datetime methods, else it may read the values a timestamp or something.

Comment: Tried that ```    data['INVDAT'] = data['INVDAT'].astype(str)    ```, now error says error: TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# get username
user = os.getlogin()


def file_process():
    data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\My Documents\\XINVST.xls')

    # Change the date and time formatting
    data['INVDAT'] = data['INVDAT'].astype('str')
    length = len(data['INVDAT'])
    data['INVDAT'].pop(length - 1)

    for i in data['INVDAT'].str.len():
        if i <= 5:
            data['INVDAT'] = data['INVDAT'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>6}'.format(x))
            length = len(data['INVDAT'])
            data['INVDAT'].pop(length - 1)
            data["INVDAT"] = pd.to_datetime(data["INVDAT"])
            data["INVDAT"] = data["INVDAT"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        else:
            data["INVDAT"] = pd.to_datetime(data["INVDAT"])
            data["INVDAT"] = data["INVDAT"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    # output to new file
    new_data = data
    new_data.to_excel('C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\Desktop\\XINVST.xls', index=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_process()
```

This is the solution, it's sloppy but works

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use `df["INVDAT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["INVDAT"], format="%m/%d/%y")`, in this case you don't need the `datetime` pakage. For further information you should look the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
data['INVDAT'] = data['INVDAT'].astype('str')
data["INVDAT"] = pd.to_datetime(data["INVDAT"])
data["INVDAT"] = data["INVDAT"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

This solution works but if the date representation is a single month like 12519 ( expected output 1/25/19), it fails. I tried using a conditional to add a 0 to the front if len() < 6 but it gives me an error that the dtype is int64.